# Table disappears when placed in LinearLayout with weight and dynamically set visibility

Tags: android

I have following layout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="300"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/add_ticket_info"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TableLayout
                    
                </TableLayout>
                  
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ticket_add_next_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

The issue is that this table disappears when I programatically set `ticket_add_next_button` visibility to `visible`. Scroll appears but I cant see nothing

Comment: I tried your layout and it shows TableLayout. Did you set also LinearLayout wrapping the TableLayout visibility to visible right?

Comment: @AbdurrahmanOğuzhanDurmaz It disapperars when I set `ticket_add_next_button ` visibility to `VISIBLE`